# Does Cloud Storage works offline in sync with Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to create an app that works offline. But i would like to store the images in Cloud Storage instead of storing it in FireStore database.

App works offline as it uses Firestore. How will it work with Cloud Storage ? Can the Cloud Storage work offline ?

Example: Device is offline. I want to push some text and image. Text goes to firestore and image should go to Cloud Storage. Can this happen ? Can the Cloud Storage Work Offline along with Firestore ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also looking for a cheap cloud database that works offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Storage for Firebase does not work offline like Cloud Firestore, and there is no automatic synchronization.  The device must be online in order for a file to be uploaded or downloaded.  If you start a transfer, and the device goes offline for a while, the transfer will be paused and resumed, but it will not continue if the app is restarted.

Comment: Firebase/Firestore has to come with lot of improvements.
1. Initially they came with Firebase with no good way of doing search queries               
2. Then Firestore with a document size of max 1MB.  They say it will work 100% offline but no good way to store images as each good image will be more than 1MB. If the document size is more then would could have stored the images here itself as bytes and everything would have worked offline. Just for the sake of images we have to use SQL Lite and maintain the images until the app comes online and push them to the cloud storage.....hmmm...